# Locked out of my Toshiba Satellite Laptop- What do I do?

Tags: windows-8, toshiba-laptop

My brother thought it would be cute if he locked me out of my local account on windows 8.1 with a new password, and yet when the joke ran out he realized he had forgotten what he changed my password to. I can't seem to access the system restore menu during startup (tried pressing f12 multiple times with no result). I do have a windows 8.1 installation disc with its activation key but I can't run it unless I log in it seems (which I can't do). Help!

Comment: There are multiple tools to recover and/or change a users passwords from outside of Windows.  Have you tried any of those tools before asking this question?

Answer (score 1):

1. By "local account " do you mean Administrator or a lower-level account? If you can access the Administrator account, see [How To Change Another User's Password in Windows 8 or 8.1](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/fl/change-another-users-password-windows-8.htm).
2. You can use [Trinity Rescue Kit](http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?content=TRINITY_RESCUE_KIT____CPR_FOR_YOUR_COMPUTER&front_id=12&lang=en&locale=en) or other tools, as @Ramhound mentions.
3. If the BIOS is password-protected, that can be reset by removing the CMOS battery (or see http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001302.htm for laptops).
4. You may lose access to some or all encrypted data if you reset your passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Boot your computer with [Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](http://www.chntpw.com/download/), the built-in chntpw tool will launch and it allows you to erase the local account password.